# SlimDX loading Image?

Tags: c#, image, slimdx

I am trying to load an image with SlimDX and render it/display it.

Here is my code:

```
MessagePump.Run(form, () =>
    {
        device.Clear(SlimDX.Direct3D9.ClearFlags.Target, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);
        device.BeginScene();
        SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture tx = 
            SlimDX.Direct3D9.Texture.FromFile(device, @"C:\d.jpg");
        sprite.Begin(SlimDX.Direct3D9.SpriteFlags.None);
        sprite.Draw(tx, new Color4(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f));
        sprite.End();
        device.EndScene();
    });
```

And the initialization of the device

```
SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters presentParams = 
    new SlimDX.Direct3D9.PresentParameters
    {
        BackBufferWidth = form.Width,
        BackBufferHeight = form.Height,
        DeviceWindowHandle = form.Handle,
        BackBufferCount = 3,
        Windowed = true
    };

device = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device(
                new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Direct3D(), 
                0, 
                SlimDX.Direct3D9.DeviceType.Hardware, form.Handle, 
                SlimDX.Direct3D9.CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, 
                presentParams
            );
```

Now i am new to this directx stuff. But from what i can it, it should work.
I get a texture, draw it with a sprite.
And the device is running at that time.

Though that being said, i am not fully clear to what´s going on behind the scenes here, but i think that loading an image and display it shouldn´t be That hard to do, so hopefully i am not totally lost with it.

EDIT: more info

Ah okay, hmm, don´t know how to assign new data to it, but will try figure it out.

The image is well a window. So if the window(game) is 800x600, then it´s probably a bit bigger, (the borders take some place). But it just looks, zoomed in for some reason.
viewport:

```
device.Viewport = new SlimDX.Direct3D9.Viewport(0, 0, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height);
```

Image: [image]

Comment: What's the question? The code looks quite ok. Except that you load the texture each frame. Do this once at the beginning.

Comment: The question is, how can i make the texture show in the window (like a picturebox).  I want to load the texture each frame, though from a stream, not the file in the example.

Comment: So I guess you don't see the texture when you run the program. Ok, what do you see? Does this change if you change the clear color? Check if the viewport has correct dimensions. Have you forgotten a `device.Present(...)`?

Comment: I see, well a white window, that´s it. Added device.present() before the loop, sadly it didn´t change anything. also made a viewport, nothing there either. PS: If i add Present in the loop, i get a picture it seems, though it´s bluish., guess though that that´s because of my draw color now that i think of it. But i also get an error it seems.

Comment: Okay i got it to work, but it´s extremely slow, and i only get half the screen for some reason. 800x600 doesn´t become 800x600, don´t know why.

Comment: The `Present()` should be at the end of the loop. It's probably slow because you create a new texture each frame. Create the texture once and just reassign new data. Can't tell you why you get half of the screen. We'll need more data for that: How large is the image? How large is the form? How have you set up the viewport? A screenshot would be nice.

Comment: @Zerowalker: Do you want your accounts merged?

Comment: minitech, yes please.

NicoShertler, added more info in the post.

Comment: As i solved this thanks to Nico, in terms of loading and displaying. I have opened a new question on how to improve it. 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29483/slimdx-display-images-quicky